# NtQueryInformationThread for both x86 and x64

Tags: c++, winapi

It seems NtQueryInformationThread needs DWORD for x86 and DWORD64 for x64 for both size and pointer variable?

How could i make it generic to compile both in x86 and x64? It seems LPVOID is not going to help because it just gave me incorrect results.

Comment: [I don't see `DWORD` anywhere in the function definition.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684283%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Am I missing something?

Comment: Since NtQueryInformationThread is defined as `typedef DWORD (*tNtQueryInformationThread)(HANDLE, LONG, PVOID, ULONG, PULONG);` and ULONG is DWORD.

Comment: That's `tNtQueryInformationThread`. Note the extra `t` in the front. That's why I found something else.

Comment: Hmmm, but again, `NtQueryInformationThread` is redefined as `tNtQueryInformationThread NtQueryInformationThread = (tNtQueryInformationThread)GetProcAddress(ntDLLHandle, "NtQueryInformationThread");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, Just found making it LPVOID makes it compilable across architecture.

`DWORD ntStatus = NtQueryInformationThread(hTemporaryHandle, ThreadQuerySetWin32StartAddress, dwStartAddress, sizeof(LPVOID), NULL);`

where `dwStartAddress` is also `LPVOID` but pointing to DWORD or DWORD64 variable according to the target environment.

Comment: DWORD_PTR is the type you should be using for x86/x64 portability.